# Prove that for the sequence $a_n=2a_{n-1}, \forall n\geq 2 \iff a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1}(a_{i})+1$ by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Prove that for the sequence $a_n=2a_{n-1}, \forall n\geq 2$ with $a_1=1$ $\iff a_n=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n-1}(a_{i})+1$

I thought about a proof by induction.
Assume that the hypothesis that $a_n=2a_{n-1}$ holds for the base-case that $a_2=a_1+1.$
We'll show that for all $n \geq2$, $a_{n}=a_{1}+...+a_{n-1}+1$

How to proceed?

Comment: Sum the recurrence relation $a_{i} = 2a_{i-1}$ over $i=2,3,\ldots,n$ and simplify. This allows you to show it *without* having to deduce what $a_i$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof without induction, and without finding the explicit formula for $(a_n)$ :**

Let $n \geq 2$. For every $k \geq 1$, one has $a_{k+1} = 2a_{k}$, so $$a_{k+1} - a_{k} = a_{k}$$ Summing these equalities for $k=1, ..., n-1$, you get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (a_{k+1}-a_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k$$

which telescopes and gives
$$a_n -a_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k, \quad \text{i.e.} \quad \boxed{a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\;a_n=2a_{n-1}\iff q:=\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=2\;$ and you have here a geometric sequence with common ratio $\;q=2\;$ , thus

$$a_n=a_1q^{n-1}=q^{n-1}=2^{n-1}$$

and by the well known formula of sum of consecutive elements of a geometric sequence:

$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\frac{a_1\left(1-2^{n-1}\right)}{1-2}=2^{n-1}-1$$

so...

Comment: Really bad for someone to have put the downvote on it. It should be reasoned.